# Find the Range from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following values

```
id Level Threshold
1   1     5000
2   2     10000
3   3     15000
```

What i need to achieve is that when i pass 6000 , I need to get Level 1.
12000 Level 2 and 16000 Level 3?

```
6000 - Level 1
12000 - Level 2 
16000 - Level 3
```

Can someone let me know how this can be achieved?

Comment: Can you explain how will this happen when you pass 6000 and you will get 12000 at level1?

Comment: What do 6,000, 12,000, and 16,000 have to do with the values in the table?  Do you need to do this for data in another table?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: I will be passing a value 6000 , i need to find the level from the above table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that when user will give 6000 then it should check which value is less than 6000 so it's 5000 and it's level is 1 same as when 12000 so it has two output as 5000 (level1) and 10000 (level2) but you need maximum one so it is 10000 (Level2). So according to this understanding the query is :

```
 select max(LEVEL) from Table where Threshold< 6000;
```

Comment: Is it helpful to you?

Comment: i am running this query for some conditions.. Thanks SNC . I will update

Answer (score 0):

How about an SQL question like this?

```
SELECT One.Level, One.Threshold
FROM
    TableName AS One,
    (SELECT MAX(Threshold) AS Maximum FROM TableName WHERE Threshold <= :value) AS Two
WHERE One.Threshold = Two.Maximum
```

Replace `:value` with `6000`, `12000`, `16000` or whatever value you are interested in. The inner query finds the maximum threshold that the value has reached. The outer query returns the level number for threshold.

*Disclaimar: I have not tested this.*

Answer (score 0):

Try Below example, might be you want below one

```
create table #temp (id int, value int)

insert into #temp values (1, 6000)
insert into #temp values (2, 12000)
insert into #temp values (3, 15000)
insert into #temp values (4, 16000)


select * from #temp 

select id, ceiling(convert(float,value)/6000) as level, value   from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c68682/1)

```
create table temp (id int, level int, Threshold int);

insert into temp values (1,1, 5000);
insert into temp values (2,2, 10000);
insert into temp values (3,3, 15000);


select max(LEVEL) from temp where Threshold<= 8000; (8000 or any other value)
```